# Using placeholder in Coil when the url is null

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide, coil

I get some data from database and push it to reciclerview. I use Coil to show images. But there are some urls that are null and I need to use some placeholder in such cases.
I tried all the option I saw in the internet but nothing helped.

```
binding.posterIv.load(UtilsUi.BASE_URL + recyclerViewItem.poster_path){
     placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_male)
     error(R.drawable.placeholder_male)
     fallback(R.drawable.placeholder_male)
}
```

When the url is null I just get empty black space.

[image]

[image]

ImageView looks like this:

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/actorImageView"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:src="@drawable/keanuriives" />
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?
P.S. Coil needs to be used, not Glide or Picasso.

Comment: `if (url == null) ...`

Comment: I just realize what is wrong. My URL is always not null because there always exists the first part of the URL (UtilsUi.BASE_URL). I need to check somehow is recyclerViewItem.poster_path is null and if it's null then show a placeholder. But not sure yet how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it but I am using Compose. You can manage the error with a state.
First declare your errorState variable at the top of your composable:

```
val imageLoadingError = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

...

```
  Image(
         painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter("yourURL",
             onError = { imageLoadingError.value = true }
         ),
         contentDescription = null,
         contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
  )
```

And the you manage the view with the state like:

```
when(imageLoadingError.value) {
true -> {Image from url}
false { Default Image }
```